# Django: Invalid block tag on line 49: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: html, django

Something wrong with my `.html` template. Can't figure the error on line 49. Says expected `endif` and I actually have it on the code.

The error says:

> Invalid block tag on line 49: 'endfor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'.

```
        44                      {% if messages %}
        45                          {% for message in messages % }
        46                              <div class=" alert alert-{{message.tag}}">
        47                                  {{message}}
        48                              </div>
        49                          {% endfor %}
        50                      {% endif %}
```

Any help would be very apprechiated.

Answer (score 2):

You might have an error here:

1 Space too much between `% }`

```
{% for message in messages %}
```